# Why is a database table called a table?

Tags: database

I've pondered the question and the most reasonable metaphor I've located is:

> a table is a surface on which items are placed

This seems a little broad, but maybe that was all of the thought put into the naming of the concept.  I've also searched Google and Wikipedia a bit and have not found a record of the inception of the term.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_(information)) is a word with more than one meaning. In this case, a table is a sort of chart, with information arranged in rows.

Wikipedia says:

"Historical relationship to furniture

In medieval counting houses, the tables were covered with a piece of checkered cloth, to count money. Exchequer is an archaic term for the English institution which accounted for money owed to the monarch. Thus the checkerboard tables of stacks of coins are a concrete realization of this information."

Comment: I suppose I should modify my question to ask about the relation of the term table in computing to the term table in furniture.  I'll be honest though, I didn't make the connection from table to chart, which is pretty embarrassing.  But the intent of the question remains, and you've answered it well.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here's [a quote from etymology online](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=table): "The meaning "arrangement of numbers or other figures for convenience" is recorded from late 14c. (e.g. table of contents, mid-15c.)."

This isn't very helpful but... People tend to name things and phenomena. Why? So we can differentiate one thing from another. (This is just a quick generalization.)

Table (and spreadsheet) are great graphic terms to imply a collection of items/stuff in sight. Graphic meaning the relation to furniture (table: "you can see the subjects on the table"). Or in a spreadsheet's case: a lot of numbers and text spreaded in the sheet(s) of paper.

These are just a couple of point of views from a non-native English speaker. Cheap answer to the original why question would be: because someone named it as a table and others agreed. It's a good term IMHO...